# uniqueness of active sheet VBA EXCEL

Tags: vba, excel

I have a question, I am having in one basic sheet, rows, for each row I create new sheet, each new sheet has in cell A3 value that I would like to use as a name for my new active sheet. Here the problem starts, as in excel the name of the sheet can only have 31 signs, some of the values in A3 are repeating because of cutting only 31 signs. For example I have in one sheet as A3 technology appliances for business and banks and in next one technology appliances for business and private. So if I take 31 signs both sheets would have the same name and I get an error that name of the sheet is already taken. In my loop I go through 1000 rows and I checked that the repeating problem would appear 700 time so I was thinking about cutting from left 28 numbers instead of 31 and add to the name number to have unique name for each sheet. Part of the code (just the part of changing the name):

```
Dim name As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim number_repeated As Integer
Dim name_signs As Integer

name = ActiveSheet.Range("a3")
name = Left(name, 31)
For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
If name <> Worksheets(i).Name Then
ActiveSheet.Name = name
Else
name_signs = ActiveSheet.Range("a3")
name_signs = Left(name_signs, 28)
name_signs = name_signs + CStr(number_repeated)
ActiveSheet.Name = name_signs
number_repeated = 1
number_repeated = number_repeated + 1
End If
Next i
```

Comment: Why do not to have a hidden sheet with in column A the real page name and in column B with a code, let's say, the initials of each word? Then you just name the sheet as the code instead of real name. E.g. `Monthly Report Of Something Really Important` as real name and then `MROSRI` as the code (and sheetname). Then in your cell `A3` you could use a `VLOOKUP` to get the right value.

Comment: is there any function to take out first letter as you did it in the example? or do you have idea how to write one? I am pretty new to VBA, but doing it manually would take too much time for 1000 cases.

Comment: Check my answer and say if it helps you ;)

Comment: To take the first letter, is quite easy: Left(str,1).

Comment: this one I know but it would only take first letter of first word.

Comment: If you want only the first letter of your entire string (`Monthly Report Of Something Really Important` would result on `M`) then just use `=Left(A3, 1)`; otherwise, if you want all the initials you could use the function I posted :)

Comment: Did some of the answers helped you @K.L?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I read way too fast, you make a logical error: one sheet is named differently means not no sheet is named this way.
You may use:

```
Public Function SheetIsMissing(s$, Optional WB As Workbook) As Boolean
    If WB Is Nothing Then Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
    SheetIsMissing = True
    On Error GoTo theend
    Dim x
    x = WB.Sheets(s).Cells(1, 1)
    SheetIsMissing = False
theend:
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

the code you have posted contains few errors:

1) `nazwa` was not declared. recommended: write `Option Explicit` at the beginning of the macro page (this will show a message if variable was not declared).

2) the code:

```
For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
If name <> Worksheets(i).Name Then
ActiveSheet.Name = name
```

will try to change every sheet to the same name.

3) `number_repeated` will never exceed 2 value, because before every time you increase it, you set it back to 1.

maybe this will do:

```
Sub Macro1()
For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    Worksheets(i).name = Left(Worksheets(i).Range("a3").Value, 28) & " " & i
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: 1. nazwa I edited for name it was a mistake,                                              3. I would move number_repeated before the loop.                                                                                                          2.  I would put name = ActiveSheet.Range("a3")
name = Left(name, 31) after for but before if. What do you think about it?

Comment: i have edited my message and added a solution you may approve.

Answer (score 0):

(**Note:** To answer a comment and avoid ugly code in the comments)

The following function can obtain the initials of a given string present in a cell, delimited by a delimiter (which is optional and has the space character as the default value) and then concatenates the current cell row to it.

```
Option Explicit

Function getInitials(sht_name As Range, Optional delimiter As String = " ")

    Dim sht_desc As String: sht_desc = sht_name.Value
    Dim str_array As Variant
    Dim split_str As Variant
    getInitials = ""

    str_array = Split(sht_desc, delimiter)
    For Each split_str In str_array
      getInitials = getInitials & Left(split_str, 1)
    Next

    getInitials = getInitials & "_" & sht_name.Row

End Function
```

**Example of usage:**

In cell `A3` is written `Monthly Report Of Something Really Important` and in `B3` is written `=getInitials(A3)`, which returns `MROSRI_3`

Comment: thank, You for the function, but I think that I still have the cases where the last word sometimes starts with the same letter so I think that first idea with numbers was better.

Comment: @K.L - New solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with acronyms

so here's a function that return the acronym of a string, based on spaces (" ") as words separator:

```
Function GetInitials(strng As String) As String
    Dim words As Variant, word As Variant
    words = Split(strng, " ")
    For Each word In words
        GetInitials = GetInitials & Left(word, 1)
    Next word
End Function
```

that you can use as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim shtAcronym As String

    For Each sht In Worksheets
        shtAcronym = GetInitials(sht.Range("A3")) '<- get the acronym out of the current worksheet "A3" cell

        '...
    Next sht
End Sub
```